# Dynamic color format values - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to color format the values (.csv file format) based on the below conditions in tableau desktop.

If consecutive increase of the values or same values with increase values from start Date then values should be Red color .

If Consecutive decrease of the values from startDate then values color should be Green Color

If  the values are Increase and then decrease from start date then Yellow.

If the values are decrease then increase then yellow.

[image]

For the above data the expected color for the student values should be below..

Student:Mon,Pat,Henry,Kim Yellow,

Jack,stanley  Red

Kevin,Lendl  -Green

I have tried below code but not working as expected..

Please correct if i missing any thing thing.

//Green - consecutive downward trend
    if
    window_sum(if FIRST() = 0 then 0
    elseif sum([Value]) < lookup(sum([Value]),-1) then 1
    end) = MAX([Number of Days]) then "Green"

```
//Yellow - downward and upward trend but not consecutive  

elseif window_sum(if FIRST() = 0 then 0  
elseif sum([Value]) < lookup(sum([Value]),-1) then 1  
end) > 0 and    
window_sum(if FIRST() = 0 then 0  
elseif sum([Value]) < lookup(sum([Value]),-1) then 1  
end) < MAX([Number of Days]) then "Yellow"  

//Red - consecutive upward trend  

elseif  
window_sum(if FIRST() = 0 then 0  
elseif sum([Value]) > lookup(sum([Value]),-1) then 1  
end) = MAX([Number of Days]) then "Red"  
end
```

Thanks for your help in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your data structure you can look into table calculations. This may not be straightforward, especially to get the "Compute Using" settings right, but some logic as follows may work.

Calculate the day on day differences (a table calculation will do that).

If the day on day diff is positive then give it a value 1, is negative set it to -1. This would be an IF statement around your table calculation.

Next SUM the result.

Calculate how many dates there are, which will provide the maximum possible number if all are increasing or decreasing every day.

Finally compare the result of the summing if up or down with the maximum possible. This field can sit on the colour shelf.

I haven't tested any of this but, from a logic perspective, you may be able to make this work.

Edit based on comments:

Build the following calculated fields, it should work. You'll be able to troubleshoot calc by calc if having "compute using" challenges. Put the [Colour] field on the colour shelf:

```
[DailyDiff]: ZN(SUM([Value])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Value])), -1)

[isUpOrDown]: IF [DailyDiff] >0 THEN 1 ELSEIF [DailyDiff] <0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END

[TotalUpOrDown]: WINDOW_SUM([isUpOrDown])

[NumDays]: {COUNTD([Date])}-1 //1 less to account for the first day

[Colour]: IF [TotalUpOrDown] = MIN([NumDays]) THEN "Increasing" ELSEIF [TotalUpOrDown]=-MIN([NumDays]) THEN "Decreasing" ELSE "Other" END
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate response !! I have tried the below calculated field..However it is not working as expected !! Please correct if i missing any thing thing.

Comment: I have added the code in main question..and the structure is same as posted in the Csv.@ 2 dimension,1 measure.Dimensions:Student,Date,Measure values.

Comment: Calculated fields are provided in the edited answer

Comment: [@Andy Colour]: ELSEIF [TotalUpOrDown]=-MIN([NumDays]) THEN "Decreasing" ELSE "Other" END

Comment: [TotalUpOrDown]=-MIN([NumDays])  is giving error:Arugument to Min (an aggregrate function is already an agrregration and cannot be further aggregrated..

Comment: when i took off min function and applied changes all of the values are displayed as others..which is not correct..

Comment: Your NumDays formula must be different to what I have. If the aggregation of {COUNTD([Date])} (the NumDays formula) is removed this would cause an error "can't mix agg and non-agg calcs". MIN could be replaced with MAX or AVG and would still return the correct result. Either way, it does need to aggregated when being compared with another aggregated value, the Window_sum in this case.

Comment: I tested all of the calculations on a simple dataset containing only the Student, Date and Value and it worked

Comment: Thank a lot !!! Issue of Aggregation is resolved with adding the parenthesis in NumDays formula which i missed out !! The results are showing correct..However i had to test with other scenario by date filter for 9 days instead of 10 days then it is not showing the incorrect results like all values turned to others which is incorrect..

Comment: The dataset will refresh incremental every day with new data for the current day plus historical data then i had to filter out or deselect for previous day..Any given point of time i had to select 10 days with previous values will be deselected from filter...This scenario is not working..Thanks for your help in advance !!

Comment: The number of days should make no difference. If the formula works for 3 days it will work for 30 days. However I suspect the issue could be with the Number Of Days formula. Try adding your date filter to context.

Comment: I have tried but no luck..Not sure where i missing..As mentioned its not working when i changed the date but it working as expected when i selected all the dates from dataset..

Comment: Any help would greatly appreciated !!

Comment: You added the date filter to context?

Comment: Ok, I don't know then. It worked for me, there must be something different at your side but I don't have enough information to know what that is. All I can suggest is you lay all of your fields out in a simple table to see what is happening with every calc to understand where it's going wrong.